# Bitmap Image Output in C

Tags: c, image

I'm working on small project in C and at one point, I need to write a picture with the content of an array to a file. This will have to run on an embedded system at some point, so additional libraries are not an option.

The code I have so far works (in a modified version) for RGB, but fails for 8bit Grayscale.

This is a stripped down version of the code so far: http://pastebin.com/U1UYAPuT

As I strongly suspect the header to be broken in some way, my question comes down to: What is a correct header for a BMP file for 8Bit Grayscale?

Comment: I know you said no library, but there's a good resource that I always use when I need bmp stuff, which worked for me in the past. It's in c++, but maybe if you don't get another answer, you could kind of reverse engineer it to see if you can spot a problem: http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/bmp_io/bmp_io.C

Answer (score 2):

Your code would be *a lot* simpler if you ditched BMP and wrote images as PGM files instead.  The format is a lot more portable and easy to work with in code.  Both formats are uncompressed so data rates would be about the same.  The only thing you would lose would be the ability to view the images natively on Windows systems -- whether or not this is a big deal depends on your requirements.

Here are some [examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format).

**EDIT**

At the very least, if you write your images in PGM **and** broken BMP, you can use [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to reliably convert the PGM to a working BMP.  Then compare the headers of the working and broken BMP images using a binary diff tool and fix your BMP writer, if required.

Comment: I use PPM/PGM images in my embedded application.  Gimp and IrfanView can display them.  Likewise, ImageMagick convert can convert them to png/jpg/bmp/whatever if needed

Comment: PGM does seem to be a lot easier, I'll check it out. Thanks!